# Getting "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" on Python while trying to read downloaded twitter txt data

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, jsondecoder

Getting "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" error when I try to read the Twitter streaming data I downloaded using Stream and saving in txt format.

Have tried various changes to the codes as suggesting in similar questions but none worked.

If I remove (errors='ignore') from open, I am getting the following error  UnicodeDecodeError

```
# String of path to file: tweets_data_path
tweets_data_path = 'Tweets.txt'

# Initialize empty list to store tweets: tweets_data
tweets_data = []

# Open connection to file
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r", errors='ignore') 

# Read in tweets and store in list: tweets_data
for line in tweets_file:
    if line.strip():
        tweets_data.append(json.loads(line))

# Close connection to file
tweets_file.close()
```

I am getting "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" error when I run the above line of codes in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: try to `print(line)` and see if it really is json type string

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I print lines I am getting these characters as well "à¤¯à¤¹ à¤•à¤¹à¤¨à¤¾ à¤…à¤­à¤¿à¤®à¤¾à¤¨à¤ªà¥‚à¤°à¥à¤£ à¤¹à¥‹à¤—à¤¾ à¤•à¤¿ à¤®à¥ˆà¤‚ à¤¦à¥‡à¤¶ à¤•à¤¾ PM à¤¬à¤¨à¥‚à¤‚à¤—à¤¾, à¤«à¥ˆà¤¸à¤²à¤¾ à¤šà¥à¤¨à¤¾à¤µ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦ à¤¹à¥‹à¤—à¤¾: à¤"°à¤¾à¤¹à¥à¤² à¤—à¤¾à¤‚à¤§à¥€" which I think is in Hindi

Comment: thats the reason why decode errors. you need to add the right encoding i guess

Comment: Your code assume that each line in the file is a valid JSON string. In order to be a valid JSON string the line first char must be '[' or '{'. What is the first char in your lines? How was this file created?

Comment: Are you sure each line of `tweets.txt` is supposed to be valid json all on its own?  json files aren't usually arranged that way.